# How can I use a single row to create multiple rows in my result set in order to create a view?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following table,

```
Emp Info1 Info2 MoreInfo
1   2     3     info_emp_1
1   2     4     NULL
2   2     6     info_emp_2
2   3     6     NULL
```

I need a result like the following,

```
1 info_emp_1   //kind of a header for emp 1
1 2 3
1 2 4
2 info_emp_2   //kind of a header for emp 2
2 2 6
2 3 6
```

I am struggling to create/fetch the header portion for each employee. I need to use the first row from the table to create the first two lines of my result set. Any help/suggestions would be appreciable.

Comment: Why do you need that? Seems to be a report output. How do you want to combine a VarChar and two numeric values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and `order by`:

```
select emp, info1, info2, more_info from mytable
union all
select distinct emp, null, null, null from mytable
order by emp, info1 nulls first, info2 nulls first
```

This yields `null` instead of some customer string for the "header" row (otherwise we would need to deal with datatype conversions).

If `info1` or `info2` may contain `null` values (which is not showing in your sample data, then you need an additional column to define the ordering:

```
select emp, info1, info2, more_info
from (
    select emp, info1, info2, more_info, 1 ord from mytable
    union all
    select distinct emp, null, null, null, 0 ord from mytable
)
order by emp, ord, info1, info2
```